# data entered in the nstableview is not saved in coredata

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

I am trying to build trival app in osx. I have made entity People with 3 fields: name, age and occupation. App is NOT document based.

ArrayController is binded with App Delegate in parameters section,and in the model key path, I have managedObjectContext

In the attributes inspector,as object controller I have entity name, and People as entity name.

Then I have binded the columns with the array controller, and as controller key I have arranged objects, and under model key path, I have name, age and occupation, (nstableview, has 3 columns).

On the end, I have 2 buttons, add and remove, which are connected with the array controller (add & remove respectively)

When I click on add button, empty record is created, I can edit it, and add the values. Remove button also works fine. But, when I close the app, and open it again, nothing seems to be preserved in core data.

I would like to mention at this point, that I didn't write single line of code so far, I am trying to do everything with binding.

Anyone can tell me what I missed to bind with what? I have searched stackoverflow and google, but I didn't manage to find any solution so far.

Regards, John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that anyone encounter the same issue...What I missed to do is connect save action  with the table view...

(right click on app delegate and drag from save action to ns table view)

When i did that, problem has been solved, and my data is now saved.